# How do I force a git merge

Tags: git, merge

I have two branches, master and a local branch.  I want to merge changes made from master to my local branch.  I know the changes in master are more recent than the ones in my local branch, but when I go to the local branch and write `git merge master`, the response is `Already up-to-date`.  I may have tricked my local branch into believing it is more current than master, I'm not sure how.

How can I force a merge conflict?  Most of the files in master are more recent than the ones in local?

Comment: You mean `git merge <remotename>/master`, don't you?

Comment: If you don't checkout master locally, pull it, then checkout your branch and merge. If you have some how managed to fool git, then that was 'erm foolish. :(

Answer (score 1):

Fetch the remote changes before merge:

```
git checkout local_branch
git fetch origin
git merge origin/master
```

I assume that you've used `origin` as the name for the remote.

Answer (score 0):

I m considering that you have the latest code in your master and it is in your workstation

```
 git checkout local;
 git merge -s ours master;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want rebase instead of merge?

Checkout local branch. Then:

```
git rebase master
```

Rebase is usually what you want when you're thinking about merge.

[Git workflow and rebase vs merge questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457927/git-workflow-and-rebase-vs-merge-questions)