# Android Studio Update Project: Merge vs Rebase vs Branch Default

Tags: android, git, android-studio, git-merge

Apologies if this seems redundant as I know there are fair amount of questions regarding Merge vs Rebase, but there doesn't seem to be any that throw in 'Branch Default' as well.

You are given a case where you have multiple people working on something (i.e. an Android app in Android Studio) concurrently. What is the best option to update project/pull if someone pushes to the master branch and you want to pull in the new master such that it doesn't overwrite the work you are still working on and have yet to commit and push to master? Android Studio lists 'Merge' 'Rebase' and 'Branch Default' when clicking 'Update Project'. From what it sounds like, I would want to do 'Rebase' (followed by 'Merge'?), but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Are all of your changes uncommitted, or do you have some changes that you previously committed but didn't push?

Comment: All changes being worked on by a user are uncommitted; any commits would be promptly followed by a push.

Comment: see [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sync-with-a-remote-repository.html)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**Stashing**

The key here is that you have uncommitted work that you want to save. Before trying to merge anything in, you should [stash your changes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing) to save your uncommitted changes and clean your working directory.

Run `git stash` to stash your changes. You should then be able to pull the changes without any issues.

After you have successfully pulled, you can do a `git stash apply` to re-apply the changes you had made prior to the pull.

**Merging and rebasing**

Stashing your changes only works if you only have *uncommitted* changes. If at some point you committed but didn't push you will need to either rebase or merge.

[This StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457927/git-workflow-and-rebase-vs-merge-questions) has some great information on the differences.

In general, merging is easier, but some believe that it "pollutes" the git history with merge commits.

Rebasing requires additional work, but since you don't have a merge commit it will essentially make the merge invisible.

Again, in your case you shouldn't need to merge or rebase. Simply stash, pull, then apply the stash and it should all be good.

Comment: I want to make this as simple as possible (i.e. only need to have the Android Studio IDE open) Is there a solution that doesn't involve using Git Bash and only utilizes Android Studio?

Comment: Nevermind, reread and seems like based on your answer I want to select 'Merge' when pulling if I want to just use AS

Comment: I wrote a new line: //test, committed and pushed it, confirmed it was pushed to master, removed the //test line locally and tried 'Update Project' with Merge and Branch default and the line didn't return. Not sure why it didn't pull the //test line from master. :X

Comment: IntelliJ (and Android Studio) [do have a stash option](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/stashing-and-unstashing-changes.html)- it is under VCS > Git > Stash changes.

Answer (score 21):

[image]

According to the IntelliJ IDEA [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/update-project-dialog-git.html?search=update%20projec):

### Update Type

- **Merge**: choose this option to have the merge strategy applied. The result is identical with that of running `git fetch ; git merge` or `git pull --no-rebase`.
- **Rebase**: choose this option to have the rebase strategy applied. The result is identical with that of running `git fetch ; git rebase` or `git pull --rebase`.
- **Branch Default**: choose this option to have the default command for the branch applied. The default command is specified in the `branch.<name>` section of the `.git/config` configuration file.

### Clean working tree before update

In this area, specify the method to save your changes while cleaning your working tree before update. The changes will be restored after the update is completed. The available options are:

- **Using Stash**: choose this option to have the changes saved in a Git
  stash, so you can apply patches with stashed changed even outside
  IntelliJ IDEA, because they are generated by Git itself.
- **Using Shelve**: choose this option to have the changes saved on a shelf.
  Shelving is a IntelliJ IDEA internal operation, patches generated
  from shelved changes are normally applied (unshelved) inside IntelliJ
  IDEA. Applying shelved changes outside IntelliJ IDEA is also possible
  but requires additional steps.

Comment: @MikeW it depends on you `.git/config`

Comment: what if I ticked "Do not show this dialog in future", how to turn back on

Answer (score 9):

I couldn't find the answer to this question (i.e. the work-flow) in any of Google's documents... so here's my practical experience using Android Studio and Git completely from a UI.

(I vomit at the thought of switching between command line and IDE - it means the IDE is lacking!)

1. Stash your changes with: Right Click Project -> Git -> Repository -> Stash Changes. Give it a name.
2. Pull updates that your colleague did with: Right Click Project -> Git -> Repository -> Pull
3. Merge back your code changes with: Right Click Project -> Git -> Repository -> UnStash Changes -> Apply Stash
4. You will then see a "Files Merged with Conflicts" UI. This is where you select a file and selectively merge.

**WARNING**

The manual merge "Merge Revisions" UI is **TERRIBLE**. Once you try it, you'll see what I mean. Good luck trying to get "Synchronize Scrolling" to actually work. I sincerely hope this UI is addressed within the first few weeks of 2015.

Answer (score 4):

**Android Studio: Merge, Rebase, Branch Default**

According to [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sync-with-a-remote-repository.html#update):

> **Merge**: select this option to perform [merge](http://schacon.github.io/git/git-merge.html) during the update. This is equivalent to running 
>  `git fetch` and then `git merge`, or `git pull --no-rebase`.
> **Rebase**: select this option to perform [rebase](http://schacon.github.io/git/git-rebase.html) during the update. This is equivalent to running 
> `git fetch` and then `git rebase`, or `git pull --rebase (all local commits will be put on top of the updated upstream head).
> **Branch Default**: select this option if you want to apply different update strategies for different branches. You can specify the default update type for each branch in the `branch.<name>` section of the `.git/config` configuration file.

[[Git Merge vs Rebase]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59267441/4770877)

Read more [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/apply-changes-from-one-branch-to-another.html)

Answer (score 3):

For those who are looking for `rebase` in Android Studio.

VCS > Git > Rebase.

[image]

[image]

Then click "Rebase", "Start Rebasing", "Merge". To simplify a process click "All" to resolve non-conflicting changes.

[image]

There may be conflicting changes, resolve them until you get a message:

[image]

If you encounter these conflicts, click left or right arrow to accept the most suitable:

[image]

Click a cross over unneccessary change to ingnore or an arrow to accept:

[image]

If you accept both changes, you can also edit the resulting code, for instance, add missing `}` in methods.

Do this until all conflicts get resolved:

[image]

Click "Apply". When all files inside one commit will be up-to-date, click "Continue rebasing" to move to the next commit.

Answer (score -1):

**Update Git project with android studio terminal**

1. git add .
2. git commit -m "anything"
3. git push origin master

This is what I was wanting to find the answer from your post. So that's why I writing this answer.