# Merge or Rebase or Branch Default In Android Studio? What are the differences?

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24393148/android-studio-update-project-merge-vs-rebase-vs-branch-default) but that did not explain Branch default. It would be nice to have a short explanation for all in one post.
thank you

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**Merge:** The result is identical with that of running `git fetch ; git merge` or `git pull`.
**Rebase:** The result is identical with that of running `git fetch ; git rebase` or `git pull --rebase`.
**Branch Default:** This option is to choose the default command for the branch applied. The default command is specified in the `branch.<name>` section of the `.git/config` configuration file.

**Example:**
Assume the following history exists

```
  A---B---C topic
 /
D---E---F---G master
```

**Merge:**
If the current branch is "master"
Then "git merge topic" will replay the changes made on the topic branch since it diverged from master.Then the result of the following command:
    `git merge topic`
would be:

```
  A---B---C topic
 /         \
D---E---F---G---H master
```

**Rebase:**
If the current branch is "topic"
Then the commits that were in the "topic" branch are reapplied to the current branch, one by one, in order.
Then the result of either of the following commands:
    `git rebase master` or 
    `git rebase master topic`
would be:

```
              A'--B'--C' topic
             /
D---E---F---G master
```

For further reference please refer the links below:
1.https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge
2.https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase
3.https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/update-project-dialog-git.html?search=update%20projec