# Merging havoc - merging two unrelated branches, each with master changes

Tags: git, github

Here's the situation:

- there's a master branch **M**
- at some point feature branch **F** was created from **M**. This should have been a main branch for a feature, and all other devs working on this feature should have branched out from this branch or work directly on this branch.
- at some point branch **F1** was created from **M**. Part of dev team created their own branch and started working on part of the feature. But they forgot to use **F**, instead they used **M**. And nobody else knew about it (including myself)

Most developers working on the feature were using **F**. They rebased **F** on **M** a few times (every time fast-forward). So far so good. However a few devs where using their **F1**, and they also rebased a few times to **M**.

Today was the day of merging to master. So devs using **F1** rebased to **F** - they reported some **merging issues** - but after a few hours they reported it's resolved and **F** has all the stuff.

Now, myself, I wanted to merge **F** into **M** and officially finish work on **F**. To my supprise, it could not be merged on github automatically. So I did **git fetch** and started rebasing **F** onto **M**. And the havoc started, conflicts. All of them appearing on files that we didn't even touch when working on **F**. I gave up after a 20-30 conflicts resolutions and **git rebase --continue** steps.

Now, when I realized (after a chat with these devs) that they had their **F1** created from **M** and not from **F**, I think I know what is causing the conflicts. Is it because changes for **M** are now being applied to **F** for the second time? Is my assumption correct? I'm not sure. But what I'm sure I don't know how to resolve this situation. I cannot merge **F** to **M** in timely manner due to infinite number of conflicts on the files that we didn't even touch when working on **F**.

Comment: IMHO the fact that they created their **F1** branch initially on **M** should not matter since you said they later rebased **F1** onto **F**. Since they used rebase, are you sure you do not have stale history on your side?

Comment: try to merge M to F, solve the conflicts and then merge back to F to M

Comment: But why I even have conflicts? I mean, conflicts are on the files that neither F1 nor F devs touched.

Comment: @wilx : stale history on my side? I don't get it. They already merged their changes (F1) into my branch (F).

Comment: How about merge F1 to M first --> Merge M to F (This is kind of merging F and F1 , you will see conflicts here) --> Merge F to M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you merge your F into M instead of rebasing F onto M, you'll have at most one conflict resolution, rather than one per commit as it seems you're experiencing.

Before you do that though… It concerns me that your devs think that neither F nor F1 touched the files that are conflicting, because a conflict proves that those files were altered in both the F branch and in master. If you weren't supposed to have changed those files, look at the history for those files with git log, and see when they were changed in F. There's a good chance that someone introduced some unintentional changes in the branch, perhaps during a rebase. Undo/revert those unintentional changes, and your conflict may become much less complicated.

```
git log -p origin/master..F -- path/to/unexpected_conflicting_file
```

Finally, unless your teams only have 1 person coding on a feature branch at a time, I would seriously consider moving from a rebase workflow to a merge workflow. Each time you rewrite a shared branch (via rebase or otherwise), it forces all other developers who share the branch to ASAP reset or rebase their branch onto the rewritten/rebased history that the rebaser pushed.  If someone forgets and pulls without resetting onto the rebased branch, then you have two versions of history that often conflict with each other. This is an error-prone and unnecessary step that can be avoided by just merging instead.

Comment: Thx a lot. Everything is clear except  I got lost after "Each time you rewrite....". Could you give an example (e.g. based on M,F,F1)?

Comment: Let's take an example from your story. Someone on your F1 team rebased their F1 branch onto the F. Assuming they're using the same branch name F1 after the rebase, they'll have to force-push F1 to rewrite/overwrite the old F1 branch (let's call it F1original) with the rebased version of F1 (let's call it F1rebased). After this push, all other developers on the team working on F1 still have F1original. If they fetch, they now have both F1 pointing to original and origin/F1 pointing to F1rebased. This is the point at which they have to do something to reconcile those two branches of history.

Comment: I'm not sure how your teams are currently handling that reconciliation. If that explanation doesn't clarify your question, please be specific about what you want clarified. :-)