# Git Rebase, Less Merges

Tags: git

I have the following situation:

```
a--b--c--d--e--f--g--h--i--j  (dev branch)
    \     \     \
     x--y--z--q--r--s         (feature branch)
```

When I merge `dev` into `feature`, I discovered I lost many (or all?) of the changes on the feature branch.  I'm guessing that too many files were touched on `dev` that overlap files on `feature`.  Regardless of the reason, this is someone else's repository I'm working with (I don't have tribal knowledge of why this occurred).

So I am interested in rebasing `feature` onto `dev` in order to replay the changes.  I figure I will capture the entire `feature` branch (back to commit `x`) but I am concerned about the merges into `feature` represented by commits `z` and `r`.  I am afraid that as a consequence of the rebase - older code from the `dev` branch will overwrite newer code on the `dev` branch.

Is that a valid concern?

If yes, what would be the easiest way for me to sift out the unique changes on the `feature` branch and replay them on the `dev` branch?  I'm not sure that cherry-picking is the right answer either.  But if cherry-picking is the right answer, can someone explain the sequence of commands I should attempt to "get it right"?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git workflow and rebase vs merge questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457927/git-workflow-and-rebase-vs-merge-questions)

Comment: Both rebase and merge should work here, please see the linked question for detailed comparison.

Comment: It's not 100% clear, but it sounds like you had conflicts at the `z` and `d` merges and took `dev` instead of resolving manually. If that's the case and you only have 3 commits I would cherry pick them. It avoids the faulty merges, and handling conflicts one at a time may be easier than all at once.

Comment: I de-conflicted the two 'd' commit names; that was a mere oversight.  I also corrected the answer from @torek to match the corrections I made in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there are plenty of *wrong* answers, there is no single *right* answer.  Note, however, that `git rebase` works by *copying* some commits, essentially,<sup>1</sup> doing a series of `git cherry-pick` operations to make each copy.  It is in general difficult to cherry-pick a merge, so `git rebase` simply doesn't bother: it just skips merges.<sup>2</sup>  This may be exactly what you want.

Suppose, for instance, that this is a literal transcription / accurate diagram of the commit graph, or at least the interesting part of it:

```
a--b--c--d--e--f--g--h--i--j   <-- dev
    \     \     \
     x--y--z--q--r--s          <-- feature
```

(except of course that each commit node has a big ugly hash ID instead of a simple one-letter name).  If we copy the *effect* of `x`, `y`, `q`, and `s` to four *new* commits that add on to commit `j`, putting them on a new branch, and rename the old `feature` to `old-feature`, we get:

```
                             x'-y'-q'-s'  <-- new-feature
                            /
a--b--c--d--e--f--g--h--i--j              <-- dev
    \     \     \
     x--y--z--q--r--s                     <-- old-feature
```

These four copies can be made by running `git cherry-pick` on the four IDs for commits `x`, `y`, `q`, and `s`, after checking out commit `j` using the new branch name `new-feature`.

Note that `git rebase` chooses *which commits to copy* using, in essence, `git rev-list <limit-hash>..HEAD`, where `<limit-hash>` is whatever you give `git rebase` as its *`<upstream>`* argument.  Choosing commit `j` suffices as this excludes the entire `a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i-j` chain from the selected commits.  We simply need `HEAD` to identify commit `s`, as it will if we check out commit `s` using our new name.

Once `git rebase` finishes the copying, it moves the current branch's name so that it points to the last-copied commit, i.e., `s'`.  So we don't even need a *new* name at all: we can just `git checkout feature && git rebase dev` and Git will copy the desired set of commits.

This does make the assumption that the graph we have drawn here is accurate.  Also, note that the way `git cherry-pick` works is to *diff* each commit against its parent.  That's why it's difficult to cherry-pick a merge: a merge commit has *two*, or sometimes even more, parents; which one should we diff against?  (Git lets you provide an answer: `git cherry-pick` gives you the `-m` option to pick which parent to use if the commit is a merge.  But we want, at least for this experiment, to *throw away* the merges, and `git rebase` does that for us.)

The drawbacks to rebasing, especially of long and detailed feature branches, are that we have to copy a lot of commits and we may get a lot of conflicts; and then *anyone else* who has the *original* commits needs to stop using them and switch to our new copies.  There is a twisty maze of fiddly little steps that can go wrong.  The advantage is that we get a simplified, cleaner history in the end, at least [if we get all the fiddly maze of steppy twists, er, maze of steppy fiddles of twisty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossal_Cave_Adventure#Maze_of_twisty_little_passages) ... [oh no, I've been eaten by a grue!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grue_(monster))

---

<sup>1</sup>Some rebases literally use `git cherry-pick`, and some do something equivalent instead.

<sup>2</sup>You *can* cherry-pick a merge, sort of; and rebase has the option to "preserve" merges; but cherry-picking a merge produces an ordinary non-merge commit, and it's not useful to attempt it in the first place, in the cases for which this is intended.  Instead, a "merge preserving" rebase *re-performs* the merges, which has its own pitfalls.  But none of that really applies here.

Comment: This is when changing careers, becoming a scuba-diver for Roto-Rooter, starts to sound attractive.  Anyway, excellent answer.