# Git and backup local commits

Tags: git, azure-devops, workflow, rebase

I've been searching around to find out what others do in this situation but I'm having trouble finding a definitive answer.

Our current workflow is as follows (btw, we use Azure DevOps for our GIT repository):

1. We have a remote 'Development' branch
2. A dev creates a new branch from remote/Development (e.g. remote/FeatureA)
3. A local copy of FeatureA is created
4. Work is done locally and committed to the local/FeatureA branch

   - As a side note, if changes are merged into remote/Development ...

     - We pull those changes into local/Development
     - Perform a rebase of local/FeatureA onto local/Development
5. Once local/FeatureA is done, it is pushed to remote/FeatureA
6. A pull request is raised to merge remote/FeatureA into remote/Development

However, any commits done locally (e.g. local/FeatureA) are not backed up in anyway and there is the potential to lose those changes if the workstation dies for whatever reason.  I was thinking it might be possible to push those commits to the remote branch (remote/FeatureA) so they are always backed up in the cloud (similar to the requirements of this poster ... [Git workflow and rebase vs merge questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457927/git-workflow-and-rebase-vs-merge-questions)).  But it appears that doing this would cause grief in rebasing should any changes be made to remote/Development by another developer.

Does anyone have a good solution for this?  That is, how can I ensure my code changes/commits are backed up while continuing to work on a Feature before it is ready to be merged into the remote/Development branch?  I supposed I could look at a hardware solution ... e.g. connect a portable HDD to my workstation and have scheduled backups ... but I thought there might be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indeed *can* backup your feature branches to the remote repo, and it *is* good practice to do so.

**So what happens if `remote/Development` is changed and you have to rebase your feature branch?**

You do as usual for the local part (pulling the new changes on `Development` then rebasing your feature on it), and yes, at this point, the remote backup is "outdated" by the rebase. But since you're not disrupting anyone else's work (or so I guessed from your description?) on *this* branch, you can then `push --force` the result of your rebased local feature branch.

I think you slightly misunderstood the part about

> "But it appears that doing this would cause grief in rebasing should any changes be made to remote/Development by another developer"

...which is true for shared stable branches like your `Development` here, but not for unshared (until they're eventually merged via a PR, of course) feature branches.

---

*(Anecdotically, we happen to have a very similar workflow in the team I'm in at the moment.)*

Comment: Perfect! Exactly the explanation I was looking for!