# What is the difference when I rebase a feature branch into master vs rebase a master onto feature, and when to use them?

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I wonder if someone can clarify what the following git actions do:

1. What happens when we checkout master and `git merge feature`?
2. What happens when we checkout master and `git rebase feature`?
3. What is the difference between the two, and in what situations would I use each of them?

Comment: See [Git workflow and rebase vs merge questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/457927/1256452) (read the whole thing, despite how long it is) and then see what questions you have left.

Comment: @torek roger that