# Why rebase and not merge main into branch before merging branch into main

Tags: git, merge, version-control, rebase

I've read in many places (including this question [Git workflow and rebase vs merge questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457927/git-workflow-and-rebase-vs-merge-questions)) that it's a good practice to do a rebase of main into local branch before merging this branch to main. but I can't understand why should I rebase main, why not just merge it to my branch?

Comment: While many people *like* rebase-oriented workflows, there's no *requirement* for them. Whether to use them is a matter of opinion. (Analogy: I may think pistachio ice cream is awful, but that does not mean you should not eat it if you like it.)

Comment: Hey, git merge creates an extra commit, however git rebase makes your history linear which would later help you to debug your bugs through tools such as git-bisect. Git rebase however messes with your history and may be bad for large number of commits. You can refer to this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/36587353/12590748

Comment: Also, I'd argue you want to rebase `local` onto `main`, not the other way round. History `main` should never be rewritten.